# PersistenceHelper checks assembly version?

Tags: serialize

In my add-in I use ESRI's PersistenceHelper class to serialize and deserialize objects to the mxd. This class however seems to compare the version of the executing assembly to the version of the assembly that was used saving the stream. If the version is not the same the stream is not loaded and the error below occurs:

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'MyAddin', Version=4.11.0.0

If I set the assembly version to a fixed version number it works. This is of course not desirable from a version management point of view. Any thoughts on solving this problem?

Comment: This is a design feature of this object. If you want to defeat it you could write your own.

Comment: How do you know that? How do I write my own persistence to the mxd?

Comment: This is more a software engineering issue than a GIS one, though your best bet is probably to talk to Esri Tech Support.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine worked it out: you have to use your own Serialization binder.

```java
Public Class AppSerializationBinder
    Inherits SerializationBinder
    Public Overrides Function BindToType(assemblyName As String, typeName As String) As System.Type
        Return Type.GetType(typeName + "," + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)
    End Function
End Class
```

And pass this to the Load method of the PersistenceHelper class like so:

```java
PersistenceHelper.Load(Of MyType)(inStrm, New AppSerializationBinder, mMyType)
```